# Mongodb: push element to nested array if the condition is met

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection:

```
{
    "_id": 11,
    "outerArray": [
        { "_id" : 21,
          "field": {
              "innerArray" : [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            }
        }, 
        { "_id" : 22,
          "field": {
              "innerArray" : [
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            }
        }, 
        { "_id" : 23,
          "field": {
              "innerArray" : [
                  2
               ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to go through all documents in collection and push to `innerArray` new element `4`, if `innerArray` already contains element `1` or element `3`

I tried to do it this way, and few others, similar to this one, but it didn't work as expected, it only pushes to `innerArray` of first element of `outerArray`

```
db.collection.updateMany( 
    { "outerArray.field.innerArray": { $in: [ 1, 3 ] } },
    { $push: { "outerArray.$.field.innerArray": 4} }
)
```

How to make it push to all coresponding `innerArrays`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is your missunderstanding a copule things.

When you do `"outerArray.field.innerArray": { $in: [ 1, 3 ] }` into your query, your are not getting only `innerArray` where has 1 or 3. You are gettings documents where exists these arrays.

So you are querying the entire document.

You have to use [`arrayFilter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update values when the filter is match.

So, If I've understood you correctly, the query you want is:

```
db.collection.update(
{}, //Empty object to find all documents
{
  $push: { "outerArray.$[elem].field.innerArray": 4 }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [ { "elem.field.innerArray": { $in: [ 1, 3 ] } } ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ra9btOerdbV)

Note how the first object into `update` is empty. You have to put there the field to match the document (not the array, the document).

If you want to update only one document you have to fill first object (query object) with values you want, for example: `{"_id": 11}`.

Comment: upvote for the mongoplayground website, didn't know it exists!