# How to update a property in a nested array with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to push a Date object from my client into the nested array 'completed_dates' but I cannot figure out how to do so, or if I would need to change my schema in order for it to work.

```
{
  _id: 606f1d67aa1d5734c494bf0a,
  name: 'Courtney',
  email: 'c@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$WQ22pIiwD8yDvRhdQ0olBe6JnnFqV2WOsC0cD/FkV4g7LPtUOpx1C',
  __v: 35,
  habits: [
    {
      _id: 6081d32580bfac579446eb81,
      completed_dates: [],
      name: 'first',
      type: 'good',
      days: 0,
      checked: false
    },
    {
      _id: 6081d32f80bfac579446eb82,
      completed_dates: [],
      name: 'seconds',
      type: 'bad',
      days: 0,
      checked: false
    },
  ]
}
```

and this is my schema

```
const habitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  category: String,
  color: {
    type: String,
  },
  date_added: {
    type: String,
  },
  completed_dates: {
    type: Array,
  }
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    max: 255,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 1024,
    min: 8,
  },
  habits: [habitSchema]
})
```

Here is what I have tried...

I've tried using findOneAndUpdate, using the document id of the logged in user, and trying to manipulate the update object to drill into the nested array. I can access the habits list of the correct user... using this code, but for this new problem, I want to go one level further and push to the 'completed_dates' array of a specific habit (based on name or _id).

```
//this only adds a habit object to the habits array.
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
    { $pull: { habits: { _id: itemsToDelete } } },
    { new: true , useFindAndModify: false},
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      } else {
        res.send(data.habits)
      }
    }
  )
```

I have tried building on this existing code by trying to filter down one more level. (this doesn't work.)

```
const { date, name} = req.body.update
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
    { $push: { 'habits.$[req.body.name].completed_dates': req.body.date} },
    {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true, useFindAndModify: false},
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      } else {
        //data.update
        res.send(data.habits)
      }
    }
  )
```

If anyone can link or help me out, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb: push element to nested array if the condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686575/mongodb-push-element-to-nested-array-if-the-condition-is-met)